# Braintree iOS v4 SDK

Tags: ios, braintree

I am integrate Braintree SDK in my app.My app Build in Swift Language. My Question is that If i am using iOS SDK in my than also it needs some setup on server side for paymentMethodNonce?

Answer (score 0):

**Generate `Nonce` for `PayPal` using `Braintree`**

```
BTPayPalRequest *request= [[BTPayPalRequest alloc] initWithAmount:amount];
        request.currencyCode = @"USD"; // Optional; see BTPayPalRequest.h for other options

        [payPalDriver requestOneTimePayment:request completion:^(BTPayPalAccountNonce * _Nullable tokenizedPayPalAccount, NSError * _Nullable error) 
          {
            if (tokenizedPayPalAccount) 
                {
                NSLog(@"Got a nonce: %@", tokenizedPayPalAccount.nonce);
               }
            else {
                // Buyer canceled payment approval 
              // Tokenization failed. Check `error` for the cause of the failure.                 
            }
        }];
```

**Generate `Nonce` for `Apple Pay` using `Braintree`**

```
// Example: Tokenize the Apple Pay payment
    BTApplePayClient *applePayClient = [[BTApplePayClient alloc]
                                        initWithAPIClient:self.braintreeClient];
    [applePayClient tokenizeApplePayPayment:payment
                                 completion:^(BTApplePayCardNonce *tokenizedApplePayPayment,
                                              NSError *error)
                                                 {
                                     if (tokenizedApplePayPayment)
                                     {
                                    NSLog(@"nonce = %@", tokenizedApplePayPayment.nonce);
                                     }
                                 else
                                     {
                                         // Tokenization failed. Check `error` for the cause of the failure.

                                         // Indicate failure via the completion callback:
                                         completion(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatusFailure);                                           

                                     }
                                 }];
```